# Retrieve Headers without API call

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4, I am wondering if it is possible to retrieve headers without making an API call. For example, our angular application is initiated with a redirect from Spring boot, certain headers are attached before loading the application. How can I retrieve these header information on bootstrap or within the application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you very much for the swift reply